# Python-Memory error while convert sparse matrix to dense matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to calculate documents' Tfidf value in python. My basic approach is the following:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5,stop_words="english")
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(clean_tweet)

tfidf_matrix=tfidf_matrix.astype('float32')
termss = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()

toarry=tfidf_matrix.todense()# this step return a Memoryerror.
```

Works perfectly fine, but unfortunately, when I try to convert sparse matrix to dense `toarry=tfidf_matrix.todense()`, python return a `MemoryError`. The tfidf_matrix has a dimension of (6602141,320297 ) and it is a sparse matrix.In addition, I have 100G of memory available.I have searched for some solutions like using `np.memmap` or `HDF5Store`,but I am not sure about that.

So does anyone have an idea of how to convert sparse matrix to dense without memory error?

P.S.
My remaining code is

```
flattern=toarry.sum(axis=0)
#flattern= map(sum,zip(*toarry))
tfidf=np.array(flattern).reshape(-1,).tolist()
merge={'terms':termss,
       'tfidf':tfidf}
tfidf_object=pd.DataFrame(merge)
#tfidf_object.index.name="termss"
#print termss[-10:],"____",tfidf[-10:]
tfidf_objects=tfidf_object.sort_index(by=["tfidf"],ascending=False)
```

I want to convert the dense matrix to a one-dimensional matrix,so I can get the top 100 tfidf-words.

Comment: 6602141*320297*4 bytes of numbers would be 7.6 TB, wouldn't it? That's why you use sparse matrices.

Comment: So why do you want to convert it to a dense matrix?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thank you for your answer,I've  perfected the question to explain my purpose.In short ,I just want to convert the dense matrix to a one-dimensional matrix,so I can get the top 100 tfidf-words.

Comment: Have you tried to do the `sum` on the sparse matrix itself?

Comment: @hpaulj yes,I have `sum`  the sparse matrix itself, but the result in different ways with `flattern`

Comment: The short answser, is you can't make a dense array this large; either you make things work with the sparse matrix itself, or you work with a smaller problem

Comment: @hpaulj ok,I see, I'll try again, thanks